# Como puedo configurar htaccess, para restringir el acceso a un WS en un ZendFramework v2.4.0?

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend

Buen día.

Tengo un servidor configurado con apache

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

y Zend Framework v2.4.0 (no puedo actualizarlo, ya que es el server del cliente).

Aplique algunas restricciones para no permitir el acceso a los archivos de configuración y algunos archivos con información sensible, mediante '*.htaccess*'.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|bak|txt|bkp)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Y funciona sin problemas.

Pero dentro del framework existe un WS (web services) que consume la plataforma para operar. El problema es que, este WS se puede ver desde URL y no tiene ninguna restricción. 
He intentado bloquear el acceso a este archivo en particular, bloquear el directorio pero sigue siendo visible.

Alguna idea de como configurar el archivo '*.htaccess*' o alguna otra forma para no permitir el acceso al WS.

De antemano, muchas gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: La parte que me extraña es que usando _Zend_ se pueda acceder a los archivos de configuración. Normalmente se separa la parte pública de la aplicación. por otra parte, ¿Quién hace uso de ese _Web Service_? Si es público, no sería necesario bloquear nada. Pero si es privado, mediante Acl puedes controlar el acceso a cualquier parte de la aplicación.

Comment: A mí también me extraño lo de los archivos de configuración. Por eso los restringí. Me llegó el un proyecto para mejorar la seguridad.
La plataforma es de uso corporativo, pero la idea es mejorar la seguridad en el acceso a la información. Tu te refieres a las listas? Puedes desglosar la idea.. Y GRACIAS por tus comentarios.

Comment: [Listas de control de acceso](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html) SI tienes configurados roles para cada usuario, incluso a visitantes, tienes control sobre a que parte de la aplicación accede cada rol. Puedes asignar privilegios de acceso por routes, por controller, por action. Es bastante flexible si se plantea bien la implementación si no la tiene. Un mismo servicio puede aplicar el control a nivel de modulo, a nivel de controlador, a nivel de action, o simplemente para controlar cualquier elemento dentro de la vista como botones, menús, etc.